# Self-employed US working in UK, paid by US Govt

Tags: united-kingdom, taxes, us-citizens

So, I have been given a research grant from the US Government in order to work at a UK educational institution. Consequently, I am on a Tier II worker visa here in England, sponsored by the UK educational institution, but "self-employed" with the grant giving me a monthly stipend. I am paid into my US bank account with US Dollars directly from the US agency; however, I am not a Government employee. I have to take the money and transfer it into GBP and then take it from there.

Here's the question:  Do I pay US or UK taxes?

Comment: Are you a US Citizen? (The answer may mean "Both")

Comment: I am a US citizen. I know I will have to probably file both, but I am unclear on which income based scheme I will have to deal with.

Comment: adding to @Gagravarr.. us citizens must _file_ regardless of residency.  but if you're outside of the us for 330 days in any one-year period, [you get a huge exclusion](http://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Foreign-Earned-Income-Exclusion).  so you send in the paperwork but you probably owe very little to the united states government for the year (you also might have to re-file to get a partial refund for the share of the previous year if your one-year period spanned a year you already paid taxes for)

Comment: Related: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2507/us-citizen-working-as-an-independent-contractor-abroad-payroll-taxes?rq=1, http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2743/taxes-and-health-insurance-us-uk-paid-by-us-govt?rq=1

Comment: Note also that any bank accounts you have in the UK will trigger US FBAR balance reporting obligations...

Comment: You asked the very same question just a couple of months ago, and accepted an answer. Why are you asking it again? Voting to close as a duplicate.